# route/redirect voip to landline with asterisk and Linksys SPA2102 or 3102

Tags: voip, asterisk, routes

I have a landline and I would like to be able to route/redirect voip to and through landline.

I am a newbie to this subject but I read [Using an Android Phone as an Asterisk extension](http://kwlug.org/node/812) which is basicaly what I would like to do but I would like to:

1. connect my landline to asterisk
2. use an android to connect to asterisk and reroute the call through the landline

I would like to be able to use CSIPSimple or some other VoIP app on my android phone to call from Android through landline.

What I miss is the way to connect my landline to asterisk. I have a a debian server running on a on old notebook and I don't have a way to put some PCI cards in it.

I found some cheap Linksys SPA2012 devices on ebay and I am not sure whether I can use this device for redirecting to landline. If not what would be a cheap solution for this?

Edit:
SPA3102 looks like a correct solution because it has phone and line-in port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best option is get some virtual pbx(asterisk based) and setup your SPA to that pbx.
After that you will be able control forwarding using browser and get calls using any sip appliation on android.
I see no easy way get that done without pbx, except option give spa3012 public ip and control redirect on device web.

SPA2XXX have no FXO port, so can't be used for landline(PSTN)